# Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to use a one to one (master, detail) relationship in Entity Framework, however, I get this error:

**Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 254, 443:Foreign key constraint 'options_Advanced_FK00' from table options_Advanced (ProductID) to table products (catalogid):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side**

Here is the association in the designer:

[image]

It says product --> 0..1 options_Advanced

I used model-first and not code first. My Options Advanced table has one product associated with each record

Products

- ID
- CatalogID
- Name

Options_Advanced

- ID
- ProductID
- Name

Comment: Try one thing: Click "Generate Database from Model" from context menu, then "Finished" (press OK on two user prompts). Come back to this mapping window and check is this same as in your above snapshot.

Comment: I get another error saying product_catalogid is not a valid column.

Answer (score 7):

I came accross this when searching for a solution to the same issue in a system I was working on.

I encountered this in VS2010 and it seems to happen when you are generating the model from the database as I was and you don;t include the objects at the same time. i.e including one table and not the other.

I got around it at this point by deleting the model and then recreating the entire model and including every table in the model that I thought I might need.

Now what happens when you add a new table I am not certain as I have not had to do this yet as I am working with an old application that we wish to convert

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem after adding a new table to my edmx. Unfortunately for me, corrupted foreign keys came along as well.

First I tried to fix it by deleting and re-adding the newly added table. That did not work.

Then, after reading this article [about the dark side of EF](http://encodo.com/de/blogs.php?entry_id=163), I ended up opting for the second solution and fixing the XML file by hand. I did it by manually deleting any foreign keys and deleting the associations.

Admittedly, this solution is far from perfect, every time I update my edmx I have to re-apply the solution again. However, since I already have to do it anyway for other tables and other problems (legacy code issues) it is an effort I really don't mind.

One thing is for sure, if you need a quick win, this is it.

Hope I've helped.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from .net 3.5 to .net 4 and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm resurrecting an old post, but I found yet a different resolution to this error.

When I received this error I was modifying an existing entity model to include new tables with foreign key constraints to a primary table. It turns out that, in the database, I hadn't set the foreign key relationships between the primary table and the newly added tables. Whoops.

After I set those relationships within the database, I then reversed all the edits I had made within the model. Starting again with a known good model, I selected 'update model from database' and got the model I was expecting, error free.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I changed the foreign keys from pointing at one table to a different one. The navigation property was cleaned up but there were still references to the old relationship hiding in the edmx. I edited the XML and manually removed the two references to the old relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when changing field attributes and relationships in the DB or in code. You may sync by updating from the database but that does not work sometimes and you get this error

The solution is to create and trigger a migration and then update the database

In the Package Manager Console run the following commands in order:

**Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges**

(give it any name when prompted)

**Update-database**

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and the problem was just that one the FK column in one table wasn't mapped to in the table mapping of the entity (designer db-first).